# Read from file and write it to another file

Tags: java, algorithm, file, bufferedreader

I need to write a file in java based on reading multiple file templates.

File template 1:

```
010 Date 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 
020 NAME 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 
030 YEAR 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 
090 xxx  131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231
```

File Template 2 :

```
010 Date 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 
040 NAME 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 
050 YEAR 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231
060 YEAR 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 
090 xxx  131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231
```

From the above two templates its clear, no of lines may vary from template to template.

The key words in the template such as date name year etc will me replaced by the value entered by the user and ll be written as a file.

User can select one template alone or combine two templates in a single file.
Ie if user selects one template then the values entered by user will replace the keywords and will writtern in a file and saved.

If user selects two templates then both the templates have to be read and saved as a single file.

**Expected o/p of such scenario using both templates mentioned above :**

```
010 uservalue 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 
020 uservalue 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 
030 uservalue 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231
040 uservalue 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 
050 uservalue 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231
060 uservalue 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231  
090 uservalue 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231
```

From the above example we can see lines in between the first and last lines of both templates are written together but first and last line are not repeated.
Because first and last line are header and footer, they cant come twice.

**Another scenario is user can select one template and request for multiple rows**

**Expected output using template 1(assume user requests for 2 rows(loops):**

```
 010 uservalue 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 
 020 uservalue 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 
 030 uservalue 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231
 020 uservalue 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 
 030 uservalue 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231  
 090 uservalue 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231 131231
```

Even here header and footer is not included under the loop condition, only the line in between are repeated.
My Code :

```
for(int i=o;i<loopcount;i++){
FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/Templates/"
                        + template[i]);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String putData=null,verify;

while ((verify = br.readLine()) != null) {

                            if (verify != null) { 
                                putData = verify.replace("YYYYMMDD", yyyymmdd);

                                putData = putData.replace("IIIIIIIIIIIIIII",
                                        imsi);
                                putData = putData.replace("DD", duration);
                                putData = putData.replace("HHMMSS", startTime);
                                putData = putData.replace("hhmmss", endTime);
                                putData = putData.replace("XXXXXXXXX", msisdn);
                                putData = putData.replace("UUUU", uplink);
                                putData = putData.replace("LLLL", downlink);
bw.append(putData + "\n");

                            }
                        }}

                        bw.flush();
                        bw.close();

                        br.close();
```

Comment: So what is your question?  What are you having trouble with?  Why are you closing the `bw` if you want to keep writing to it?

Comment: my question is I want the lines in between first and last line to be written n no of times based on loopcount length, but the fisrt and last line should be written once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the lines in the template.. 
store the 1st and nth value
loop the file content if 1 or n matches with the line number .. store them separately...

perform string manipulations...
append all variable and write them into another file...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand the logic of the parameters-replacement in your code so I can't suggest an actual edit, but if you need to handle the first and last files in a special manner, you can try something like:

```
... {preceding code}
    verify = br.readLine());
    putData = verify.replace("YYYYMMDD", yyyymmdd);
    bw.append(putData + "\n");

    String strTempValue = null;
    boolean isLastLine = false;

    do {
        strTempValue = br.readLine();
        isLastLine = (null == strTempValue);
        if (verify != null)
        { 
            if(isLastLine)
            {
                // your footer logic
            }
            else
            {
                // file template body - "normal lines"
                putData = verify.replace("YYYYMMDD", yyyymmdd);

                putData = putData.replace("IIIIIIIIIIIIIII", imsi);
                putData = putData.replace("DD", duration);
                putData = putData.replace("HHMMSS", startTime);
                putData = putData.replace("hhmmss", endTime);
                putData = putData.replace("XXXXXXXXX", msisdn);
                putData = putData.replace("UUUU", uplink);
                putData = putData.replace("LLLL", downlink);

                verify = strTempValue;
            }

            bw.append(putData + "\n");
        }
    }
    while ((verify = br.readLine()) != null);
```

Comment: not first and last files, first and last lines of a file.

Comment: To make it simpler to you, File template that i mentioned above has to be read. If count is 1 I want the out put to be like **Output file 1** Mentioned above. If count is 3 I want the output to be like **Output 2** mentioned above. In output 2 first and last line of template is printed once but lines in between them are printed thrice (count=3)

Comment: Okay, i edited the code. Basically the idea is to read the first line outside the loop (and process it as the header) and then inside the loop always read one line ahead - if there's nothing "there" it means you've reached the EOF and you should handle the "current" line as per your footer login. Notice the change from "while" to "do-while" which is to prevent the loop from reading the file (and breaking the "what's next" logic).

Comment: I think you have got my question wrong, am sorry that I did not add clear explanation I will edit my question, kindly help me with that